# R language: plot grid lines only inside the graph

Tags: plot, r-grid

I am trying to remove all grid lines outside the graph. I noticed that behavior in R is not deterministic, i.e., sometimes grid lines are inside the graph only (as I want), but sometimes it spans an entire figure (see [sample](http://postimg.org/image/62fdwry93/)). I'd like to always put grid lines inside.

I read grid [manual](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/grid.html), but could not find an option to do so. abline() also puts grid lines across an entire figure.

The code I am using is

```
plot(xrange, yrange, type="n", xlab="X", ylab="Y", xlim=c(200,1500), ylim=c(0,10000))
...
grid(lty=3, col="gray")
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks,

Nodir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I have had this problem it is because `par(xpd=TRUE)` is somewhere in the code. Try setting `par(xpd=FALSE)` before using `grid()` and then `par(xpd=TRUE)`. The sample code was used to generate the same the two plots, one of which has the grid lines extending outside of the plot region.

[image]

[image]

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)

# scatter plot with gridlines inside
par(xpd=FALSE) # do not plot outside the plot region
plot(x,y)
grid(lwd=2)

# scatterplot with gridlines outside the region
par(xpd=TRUE) # plot outside the plot region
plot(x,y)
grid(lwd=2)
```